# レビューキューの処理中に投稿をフォローできない

Tags: バグ, 完了, レビュー

レビューキューの「初めての投稿」で投稿を表示している最中、"フォロー" のリンクをクリックしても反応しません。

- 同じ画面で表示されている別項目の "編集" 、"閉じる" 等は問題なく反応します。
- "フォロー" も、レビューキューではなく質問ページを開いた際には反応します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

(追記)
MSE でも既に同様の報告がされており、ステータスも [status-planned] になっていました。

[Unable to follow while in Review Queue - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350648)

コメント欄でのやり取りによれば、"表示が切り替わらないだけで、実際には機能している (けど分かりづらいよね)" そうです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MSE での関連投稿](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/350648) が、2021/01 時点で "[status-completed] = 解決済み" となっていました。

日本語版においても正常な動作を確認できたので、いったん解決済みにしたいと思います。